# Trying to create a dynamic grid of JPanels - Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

Good evening once more! 
I've been trying some days now to create a method/class that will automatically generate a grid of X*Y JPanels inside a Netbeans GUI-Builder interface.. The thing is, I've tried every single YouTube video or post to achieve it, but none of them seem to work.
I have created a class extending the JPanel class, but the panel (with colored background) won't appear inside the gui, although I've put all the necessary alignments.. Is there anyone who can help with this one..? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:: I've cleared the code of the classes created for this, as they did not work.. I have 2 textboxes and a button with which I want to generate a "dynamic" table of JPanels.. One textbox for the Width and one for the height of the table.  I'll rewrite the previous code and post it when I have access to my laptop!
EDIT2:: So I've returned to my laptop, I followed an instruction from the comments to try and create it with Rectangles. So I did. Here is my Class:

```
package worldedittor.gui.grid;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class DrawingCanvas extends Canvas {

    private int width, height;
    Rectangle[][] recsTable = new Rectangle[this.width][this.height];

    public DrawingCanvas() {

    }

    public void setNewDimension(int width, int height) {
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setSize(width*32+1, height*32+1);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        createGrid();

    }

    public void createGrid() {
         for(int y=0;y<this.height;y++) {
             for(int x=0;x<this.width;x++) {
                 this.getGraphics().setColor(Color.black);
                 this.getGraphics().drawRect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32);
             }
         }
     }    
    }
```

Now the only problem is that, When I press my button, the Canvas appears, BUT the grid doesnt show up. Actually, it "tries" to load but then wipes off.. If I press the button again, the grid is drawn successfully. Here is the code of the button:

```
private void applyBtnAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int enteredWidth = Integer.parseInt(worldWidth.getText());
    int enteredHeight = Integer.parseInt(worldHeight.getText());


    drawingCanvas.setNewDimension(enteredWidth, enteredHeight);
}
```

Any help on that? Thanks again! After this rendering process I'll follow the instruction to use the `contains` method.

EDIT3:: So I kind of fixed it. The solution was really weird. I knew I had to write the paint(Graphics g) method again, but since I override it, it works. Here's my fix:

```
....
public void setNewDimension(int width, int height) {
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setSize(width*32+1, height*32+1);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    //createGrid();

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    createGrid();
}
....
```

Comment: Maybe post some code of your jpanel and config and the algorythm to create it. What´s the reason you want to do this - so many jPanels? maybe there are better ways...

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: @LenglBoy I want to generate a table of JPanels so I can draw a "map" on them. Clciking a button to set a texture. As I editted on the question, I'll have more information later today due to no access to my laptop!

Comment: and this is not going with rectangles and a canvas field?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @LenglBoy I've added the source code I wrote based on your comment!